# Javascript : How access to a local function from global code

Tags: javascript, html

I have a function inside of an immediately invoked function expression and I want to be able to access that function globally without lexically scoping it that way.

How can I access this "private" function through a namespace called "App"?

**indew.html:**

```
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <title>Test</title>
            <script src="filtering.js"></script>

        </head>
        <body>
            <article>
                <p>
                    Computer graphics is widespread today. Computer imagery is found on televi
                    surfaces, illumination sources, and so forth, perhaps with a dynamic (time) component".[3]
                </p>
            </article>
        <section id="result"></section>

        <script>
            App.showOccurenceFiltering();  // here is my wrong call
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**js script :**

```
var App = (function () {
function showOccurenceFiltering() {
    "use strict";
    var filteredWordsArray = filtering(),
        resultView = "<ol>";
    for (var i = 0; i < filteredWordsArray.length; i++) {
        var partWord = filteredWordsArray[i].substring(0, filteredWordsArray[i].indexOf(" ")),  // de 0 jusqua l espace : la partie mot
            partNumber = filteredWordsArray[i].substring(filteredWordsArray[i].indexOf(" ") + 1); // de l'espace à la fin : la partie number
        resultView += "<li>" + partWord + " (" + partNumber + ")</li>";
    }
    resultView += "</ol>";
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = resultView;
}
}(App));
```

so i got an error of a miss call like shows the capture :
[image]

**how should i resolve my problem ??**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to expose the function to the global scope. You can do this with a namespace, like this:

```
(function () {
   function showOccurenceFiltering() {
    "use strict";
    var filteredWordsArray = filtering(),
        resultView = "<ol>";
    for (var i = 0; i < filteredWordsArray.length; i++) {
        var partWord = filteredWordsArray[i].substring(0, filteredWordsArray[i].indexOf(" ")),  // de 0 jusqua l espace : la partie mot
            partNumber = filteredWordsArray[i].substring(filteredWordsArray[i].indexOf(" ") + 1); // de l'espace à la fin : la partie number
        resultView += "<li>" + partWord + " (" + partNumber + ")</li>";
    }
    resultView += "</ol>";
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = resultView;
   }

   // Prepare a "dummy" object
   var obj = {};

   // Attach the private function to this object
   obj.showOccurenceFiltering = showOccurenceFiltering;

   // Attach the dummy object to the global scope in a controlled namespace:
   window.App = obj;

}());
```

Then you can access the function like this:

```
 App.showOccurenceFiltering();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following:

```
var App = (function(){
var obj = {};
obj.showOccurenceFiltering = function() {
    "use strict";
    var filteredWordsArray = filtering(),
        resultView = "<ol>";
    for (var i = 0; i < filteredWordsArray.length; i++) {
        var partWord = filteredWordsArray[i].substring(0, filteredWordsArray[i].indexOf(" ")),  // de 0 jusqua l espace : la partie mot
            partNumber = filteredWordsArray[i].substring(filteredWordsArray[i].indexOf(" ") + 1); // de l'espace à la fin : la partie number
        resultView += "<li>" + partWord + " (" + partNumber + ")</li>";
    }
    resultView += "</ol>";
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = resultView;
}
return obj;
}());
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `App` variable remains `undefined` because the *Immediately Invoked Function Expression* does not return a value.

Instead, define `App` as an object literal, as follows:

```
var App = {
    showOccurenceFiltering: function() {
        "use strict";
        var filteredWordsArray = filtering(),
            resultView = "<ol>";
        for (var i = 0; i < filteredWordsArray.length; i++) {
            var partWord = filteredWordsArray[i].substring(0, filteredWordsArray[i].indexOf(" ")),  // de 0 jusqua l espace : la partie mot
                partNumber = filteredWordsArray[i].substring(filteredWordsArray[i].indexOf(" ") + 1); // de l'espace à la fin : la partie number
            resultView += "<li>" + partWord + " (" + partNumber + ")</li>";
        }
        resultView += "</ol>";
        document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = resultView;
    }
};
```

Now your call will be valid.